# Terminal's window auto reduce size when click

Tags: gnome-terminal, window

I have a weird thing which happening on my system, anytime when I click in/out window of terminal, it auto resize to smaller.

I have uploaded video for this case: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XHGjmAG8Y8Mb1qXZ9

Please let me know what I mistake, also what I can do to fix it. Thanks so much!

I had reinstalled clean OS and gnome-terminal is ok, but mate-terminal still error. And I found: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/issues/350

UPDATE with fixed:

- Disable Wayland and switch to Xorg
- If it running on VMware, disable 3D Accelerate for VMware.

Comment: You've tagged your question with `gnome-terminal`, however the top bar of your desktop clearly shows that it's `mate-terminal`. Just wondering, can you reproduce the issue with `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Hi egmont, gnome-terminal and mate-terminal had same issue, so I just record mate-terminal for example. Thank you.

Comment: Include version information: Ubuntu version and version of the terminal. Describe specifically steps a user can do to try reproduce the issue without having to look at a video. Add all information to your question, not in a comment: use edit.

Comment: I had reinstalled clean Ubuntu 22.04 and Gnome-Terminal without issued, but Mate-Terminal still error. So, I think this issue from mate-terminal. I will update my first post with reproduce soon. Thanks.